# BitmapImage throw System.DividByZeroException in NUnit for Windows Phone unit testing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nunit

I have a photo app on Windows Phone 7 and now trying out NUnit for writing some unit tests. I am trying to load some images from the embedded resources and I tried two different approaches but none of them works for me...

1. This gives me System.DivideByZero exception when instantiating BitmapImage object

   ```
   BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("data/data000.jpg"));
   WriteableBitmap testData = new WriteableBitmap(image);
   ```
2. This give me "Unable to determine application identity of the caller." when calling PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg().

   ```
   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Test.data.data000.jpg")) {
     WriteableBitmap testData = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(stream);
   }
   ```

Any idea what else I should do or try?
I tried NUnit (from NuGet) and NUnit-WindowsPhone (also from NuGet).

Thank you very much!

EDIT: One thing I need to add is that I am running test cases through Resharper, I am not sure if that matters...

Regards,
Kane

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly you have to set "copy local" to true on all the references except mscorlib in the unit test class library.

EDIT: I believe your best bet will be to rewrite the code, so you only have the image name in your viewmodel (if you're using MVVM?). Then you can test your own logic, that you're picking the correct image etc. It's pointless to test the BitmapImage/WriteableBitmap anyway.

The pains of running Silverlight code in a non-Silverlight runtime...

Comment: Yes, I did that to all references except mscorlib. (How about mscorlib.extensions?)